# Second line of a TextView inside of a Table Row is not truly text aligned but the first line is ok

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView inside of a Table Row,

The TextView supports Multi-line capability

The Gravity is set to Left

The problem is the first line of the text is Left aligned but the next line of the text is Right aligned as below:

```
|This is the mentioned text 
        which has a problem|
```

Where I need the following text:

```
|This is the mentioned text 
 which has a problem       |
```

Some code:

```
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_1_Row_29"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/table_1_Row_29_text1"
                    android:layout_span="6"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

            </TableRow>
```

And:

```
mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_1_Row_29_text1().setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oh,it was not set as Left aligned

It is Right aligned and the first line was large enough to fill the whole space and it

seems that the first line is truly left aligned